# c# polymorphism

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism

I'm new to polymorphism and struggling a little bit.

I have three classes. The Visit class which is the base class. Then there is delivery and pickup.

Both delivery and pickup are visits.

I want to be able to reference the visit class and speak to both delivery and pickup.

```
    public virtual class Visit
    {
    private string customerName;
    private string customerAddress;
    private DateTime arrivalTime;

    public string customername
    {
        //name properties
        set { customerName = value; }
        get { return customerName; }
    }

    public string customeraddress
    {
        //address properties
        set { customerAddress = value; }
        get { return customerAddress; }
    }

    public DateTime arrivaltime
    {
        //time proerties
        set { arrivalTime = value; }
        get { return arrivalTime; }
    }
}

public class Delivery : Visit
/*
 * Polymorphism, Delivery is also a visit.
 */
{
    private string deliveryAddress;
    private string deliveryName;

    public string deliveryaddress
    {
        set { deliveryAddress = value; }
        get { return deliveryAddress; }
    }

    public string deliveryname
    {
        set { deliveryName = value; }
        get { return deliveryName; }
    }

    public string ToString()
    { //return Delivery details
        return deliveryname + " " + deliveryaddress + " " + customername + " " + customeraddress + " " + arrivaltime;
    }

}

public class Pickup : Visit
/*
 * Polymorphism, pickup is also a visit.
 */
{
    public string ToString()
    { //return Pickup details
        return customername + " " + customeraddress + " " + arrivaltime.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question? If you want to inherit classes then you are almost there, I can only see that the base-class is declared virtual, which is not a valid option. If you remove that, then the inheritance should be fine.

Comment: When I reference the Visit class I can't access the properties of the Pickup class.

Comment: If you want the Visit class can not be instanced, you could declare  Visit class as an `abstract` class.

Comment: I wouldn't expect that you could. `Visit` doesn't have any `Pickup` properties.

Comment: Do you have any build errors? Since you cannot declare a class 'virtual', you can declare a class 'abstract' but that is not required.

Comment: @ScottRobertson Correct, the Visit class is the BASE class, and the base-class has to knowledge of the derived classes. Any derived classes knows the base-class.

Comment: But even so, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve or what exactly you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove `virtual` from the base class

```
Visit v=new Pickup();
v.customeraddress = "some address";
v=new Delivery();
v.customeraddress = "some address";
```

As you can see in the above example `v` is a type of `Visit` but I'm allow to make it to point to an instance of `Pickup` or `Delivery` having a different behavior against the instance type assigned.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly...

Your scenario is you have a `Visit` object and want to get the details depending on whether it is a `Pickup` or `Delivery`. As long as you have created the `Delivery` or `Pickup` object during run-time, you can do a:

```
Visit v = GetVisit() //or whatever your method is
if(v.GetType() == typeof(Delivery))
{
    Delivery d = v as Delivery;
}
else //Must be Pickup
{
    Pickup p = v as Pickup;
}
```

You can then use the object, which by design will show you the Visit variables as well as the unique variables of that class.. for example... `d.customeraddress`

This doesn't work when the Visit object is taken from an already existing source (such as a flat file, or database). If that is the case, you will need a property in the `Visit` class such as `bool AmIDelivery` or an Enumeration class if you plan to increase the classifications further down the line. You can then look at this variable and behave accordingly - but you will need to create the cast object before it can be used. If this is going to be a problem for you, I can show an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your base class to not be instantiated (i.e. a `Visit` object makes no sense, it's either a `Pickup` or a `Delivery`) you can declare the base class as `abstract` and not `virtual`

After that, you can use polymorphic code as much as you like. For example:

```
List<Visit> visits = new List<Visit>();
visits.Add(new Pickup{ ... some properties set here ...});
visits.Add(new Delivery{ ... some properties set here ...});

// writes out a pickup via a polymorphic call
Console.WriteLine(visits[0].ToString()) 
// writes out a delivery via a polymorphic call
Console.WriteLine(visits[1].ToString())
```

However, if you want to use delivery specific properties, you can't use that because the reference to e.g. `visits[0]` is of type `Visit`, even if the object referenced is of type `Delivery`. To use them, you would need to check for the runtime type of the object and cast them to the specific sub-type, along these lines:

```
foreach (Visit visit in visits)
{
   if (visit is Delivery)
   {
       Delivery d = (Delivery)visit;
       //delivery specific code here
   }
   else if (visit is Pickup)
   {
       Pickup p = (Pickup) visit;
       //pickup specific code here
   }
   else
   {
       //unknown descendant, panic
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism means that an implementation in a base class could be overwritten in a derived one.

In your case, excepting the `ToString()` override, everything is about *inheritance*.

Be aware that in your code you're hiding the `ToString()` method. C# allows you to add members to inherited classes with the exact identifier of the parent one, but this isn't polymorphism.

Your derived classes will do *polymorphism* if the whole `ToString()` is marked with the `overrides` keyword:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return base.ToString(); // Change this line with any custom action
}
```

Other detail is that classes couldn't be *virtual* but members can. Classes can be `regular` (allowing polymorphism) or `sealed` (it can't be inherited).

Hmmm... Do you know what's *upcasting* and *downcasting*?

#### Downcasting

Casting a reference to a more concrete type. For example:

```
Visit visit = new Delivery();
Delivery delivery = (Delivery)visit; // This is a downcast!
```

#### Upcasting

Casting a reference to a less concrete type. For example:

```
Visit deliveryTypedAsBaseClass = new Delivery() // This is an upcast!
```

### Ok

Then, since C# is a statically-typed language, *typing* means that a variable typed as `Visit` will have access to its own members. If you need to access `Delivery` members, **you need to downcast it!**